# @PreAuthorize Does not restrict user from Access Controller Action

Tags: spring-mvc, grails, spring-security

Using Grails [Spring Security](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and [Spring Security ACL](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl).
I have a controller:

```
class AdminCompanyController {

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  def create() {
    println("create")
    [company: new Company()]
  }

}
```

Even a user which has only role `ROLE_USER` can access the `create()` action.

I know I can do it with the spring security annotation `@Secured` but I want to do it with ACL.

**How do I prevent a User which does not have `ROLE_ADMIN`from access to the `create()` action using ACL?**

Edit: I use Grails 2.4.5 and

```
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
    runtime ':spring-security-acl:2.0-RC2'
```

Comment: Have you added ```@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)``` to your security configuration?

Comment: No where do I have to place it? Could you please post a short example?

Comment: @Mati Recall that I want to use ACL?

Comment: This annotation should enable annotations like ```@PreAuthorize``` which is also part of ACL. Which version of grails do you use?

Comment: @Mati I posted it in my edit. The dependency for ``@ EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`` cannot be resolved.

Comment: Have you solved it yet? As @Mati said you should add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` to you security configuration class.

Comment: @What does this annotation do?

Comment: @Mati this is the correct answer -> @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

Answer (score 0):

@PreAuthorize has to be used in Services. In controllers you have to stay with @Secured.

Comment: It actually can be used on Controllers